# What's the fastest a Space Marine can run in Deathwatch?

Tags: optimization, warhammer-40k, deathwatch

[Some effort has gone into calculating how fast the theoretical Brother Flash of the Blood Angels can run](http://suptg.thisisnotatrueending.com/archive/15141246/), but rule interpretation, determining the order modifiers come in and if they add up or multiply gives several different results.

So I ask of you: what is the fastest a Space Marine can run in Deathwatch, including the use of a jump pack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**316.8 kph** at least, depending on calculation order. Up to **736.4 kph**.

The calculation you linked is mostly correct up until the unnatural bonuses.

Unfortunately, only Unnatural Speed affects speed at all.

So I will repeat it here again:

- 50 starting agility
- +5 from being a Raven Guard
- +5 from armor history
- +10 from power armour mk6
- +20 from all of the advances

for a total of 90 agility. That's +9 bonus, which raises to +13 with burst of speed solo mode ability. That means movement rate of 14/28/42/84.

Now, let's heap things up.

- Sprint talent doubles the running distance.
- Wings of the Raven jump pack triples base movement.
- Dilation Field gives Unnatural Speed (also Unnatural Agility, which is irrelevant here).
- Wings of Angels assault marine ability increases jump pack movement rate by 20.

So, an x2 bonus, x2 bonus and an x3 bonus, which together give us a whopping x5 bonus. And a flat addition to movement rate, which I'm really unclear as to when to apply.

Anyway, the final running speed will be no less than 440. Rounds being 5 seconds long, that's 88 meters per second, or 316.8 kilometers per hour.

If Wings of Angels add to base move, we'll have running speed of 1020. That's 204 meters per second, or 736.4 kilometers per hour - a bid to outrun a jet!

Comment: Huh, I thought that this trick was Blood Angels only. What book is the Wings of the Raven Jump Pack from? And how did you arrive at an x5 bonus by adding an x2, x2 and x3 bonus?

Comment: The standard logic in DW is: two doubles add up to a triple. See str multiplication for thunder hammer, for example. Wings of Raven are from First Founding, iirc.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with 351.36km/hr as my fastest with Blood Angel Assault marine.

1. Stats

   - Base Ag 50
   - +5 from Chapter
   - Assumed +5 from Armour history (Fury Like Lightning)
   - Assumed +10 from Mk 6 armour
   - +20 from experience
   - Total 90 for Ag bonus of 9
2. Codex solo mode Burst of speed give an extra 4 so that's 13
3. Dilation field gives unnatural speed so 13 doubles to 26m
4. Jet Pack (Wings of Saronath) triples movement rate so that 78m.
5. Run action is 6 times Half move so that's 468m
6. +20 flat from Wings of Angels Assault Marine ability 488m in 5 seconds.
   97.6 m/s or 351.36 km/hr

Note:

1. Following the rule of thumb of multiplication before addition.
2. I don't think Sprint and Jet Pack stack. The description for jet pack states "An Astartes Jump Pack allows for a safe, guided fall from any height, and any number of short jumps. Such jumps allow the Battle-Brother to double his Base Movement and
   travel in any direction without regard for obstacles. For all other purposes, he counts as having taken the appropriate Movement action." Whereas Sprint seems to imply that you have to run on the ground.