# How is movement distance calculated with my jump pack?

Tags: warhammer-40k, deathwatch

We have been playing a Deathwatch campaign for a while. I am an Assault Marine with Agility 50, and I'm starting to think I've been underselling myself on movement this entire time.

So far I've been playing with my movement calculated as follows:
Ag Bonus = 5, +1 for power armour = 6.  Per table 1-3 in Core Rulebook p. 27, movement is therefore 6/12/18/36.

I was just reading about the Wings of Sanorath in RoB and it says they "triple normal movement instead of doubling it".  I went back to the Core Rulebook and apparently I can make "any number of short jumps" which double my Base Movement speed.

So my questions are:

1. Does the jump pack indeed just double my movement for all
   purposes, or do I need to specifically use it for "small jumps" as
   the Core book says?
2. Does this doubling occur before the +1 for power armour (i.e.
   11/22/33/66) or after (i.e. 12/24/36/72)?
3. Can I even have an Agility Bonus for movement calculation in
   excess of the limit 10 on table 1-3? Or is this just the extent of
   the table for practicality/demonstration purposes, and there is no
   upper limit on my movement?
4. The alternate use of my jump pack is Flyer(12). Does that mean
   that in Flyer mode my movement is 12/24/36/72?
5. I also took Wings of Angels, which lets me add 20m to "the
   movement rate of the jump pack". Presumably this is after doubling?
   So for example I would go from 12/24/36/72 to 32/44/56/92?

Answer (score 2):

**Jump Packs** (p. 171) modify your normal movement speed, but as with other equipment and talent calculations (the order is *normally* base, then talents, then equipment), those are applied *after* your normal stats. So, it doubles your movement of 6, 12, 24, 48 to **12, 24, 36, 72**, and allows you to ignore obstacles and difficult terrain in your path. Those are the so called *short jumps*.

As for de **Flyer (12)** ability, that is a different movement type, and is described under traits (p. 132) as:

> A creature with this trait has the natural ability to fly, whether with broad leathery wings, strange warp energies, or inflatable gas sacs. This trait always includes **a number to indicate at what speeds it moves** when it flies.

So, with flyer 12, your base movement is 12, and works just like normal movement (as described on p.210 in detail):

> This number describes the character or creature’s Flying Movement. **This works just like regular movement**, but applies only when the creature is flying. While flying or hovering, a creature must devote a Movement Action to maintaining its flight each Turn, or it falls.

**Wings of Angels** (p. 73) describes only that it adds +20 meters to your **movement rate** (the same described on p. 205) on a successful check, but doesn't go into detail on how this increase works. As such, it isn't clear on how this bonus is calculated, but most people assume its +20m on top of your base movement when flying. So, from *Flyer (12)*, you go to **Flyer (32)** for a single round.

By the way, you might be interested on [this other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/55151/21153) about movement speed for assault marines.